# Parse multi level JSON from URL

Tags: json

All.

I found this script which is rather promising for what I am trying to do.
It works great with the hardcoded XML script.
However, I need to parse the file itself from an external URL.

Thank You.

Contents of the example file.

```
{"icestats":{"admin":"admin","host":"192.168.2.203","location":"Radio","server_id":"Icecast 2.4.4","server_start":"Mon, 24 May 2021 16:54:10 +0000","server_start_iso8601":"2021-05-24T16:54:10+0000","source":{"audio_info":"channels=2;samplerate=44100;bitrate=256","channels":2,"genre":"various","listener_peak":3,"listeners":2,"listenurl":"http://192.168.2.203:8000/RadioOne","samplerate":44100,"server_description":"Unspecified description","server_name":"RadioOne","server_type":"audio/mpeg","stream_start":"Mon, 24 May 2021 21:59:34 +0000","stream_start_iso8601":"2021-05-24T21:59:34+0000","title":"KISS - Hide Your Heart","dummy":null}}}
```

Example of the linked file. (This is an example of the URL file, in the real-world URL, it will be my domain name, with the file attached to it. This file cannot be removed from the location it is at, it is sitting on another server in the network.)

```
http://192.168.2.203:8000/status-json.xsl
```

Full script (This will run and show the hardcoded XML tree without any modifications to the file)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Parse Nested JSON Data in JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    /* Storing multi-line JSON string in a JS variable
    using the new ES6 template literals */
   var json = '{"icestats":{"admin":"admin","host":"192.168.2.203","location":"Radio","server_id":"Icecast 2.4.4","server_start":"Mon, 24 May 2021 16:54:10 +0000","server_start_iso8601":"2021-05-24T16:54:10+0000","source":{"audio_info":"channels=2;samplerate=44100;bitrate=256","channels":2,"genre":"various","listener_peak":3,"listeners":2,"listenurl":"http://192.168.2.203:8000/RadioOne","samplerate":44100,"server_description":"Unspecified description","server_name":"RadioOne","server_type":"audio/mpeg","stream_start":"Mon, 24 May 2021 21:59:34 +0000","stream_start_iso8601":"2021-05-24T21:59:34+0000","title":"KISS - Hide Your Heart","dummy":null}}}';
   
   
   // This is the link to the file; the file contents are what is above.
   //var json = "http://192.168.2.203:8000/status-json.xsl";
    
    // Converting JSON object to JS object
    var obj = JSON.parse(json);
    
    // Define recursive function to print nested values
    function printValues(obj) {
        for(var k in obj) {
            if(obj[k] instanceof Object) {
                printValues(obj[k]);
            } else {
                document.write(obj[k] + "<br>");
            };
        }
    };
    
    printValues(obj);
    
    document.write("<hr>");
    document.write(obj["icestats"]["source"]["title"]); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the script with the URL link only, I get the following error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at music2.asp:18
```

Which points to this line.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

Comment: i tried running `var json = ...` and `var obj = JSON.parse(json);` in browser console, it's working as expected.

Comment: Did you try the example with the URL and NOT the hardcoded XML?

Comment: My bad, now i get  it, can you please upload file since the file is not accessible from outside since you shared local IP address, try accessing it from some other network.

Comment: All you have to do is take the script which is in the "Contents of the example file." Save it to a file called: status-json.xsl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code was provided for me and it works great.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Zvonko &#42;</title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
   // fetch the JSON data from your URL:
   jQuery.get( "http://localhost:8000/status-json.xsl" , showData, "json" );

   function showData(data){
      // no need to Converting JSON string to JS object
      // jQuery converted it for you
      //var obj = JSON.parse(data);
      printValues(data);
      document.write("_______________________________");
      if(data["icestats"] && data["icestats"]["source"]){
         document.write(data["icestats"]["source"]["title"]);
      // This next line, I use to pass a variable to an input field to submit to the database.
      $(".myid").val(data["icestats"]["source"]["title"]);
      }
      
      // Converting your JSON string from top to JS object
      var jsonobj = JSON.parse(yourJson);
      printValues(jsonobj);
      document.write("_______________________________");
      if(jsonobj["icestats"] && data["icestats"]["source"]){
         document.write(jsonobj["icestats"]["source"]["title"]);
      }
    }
   
    // Define recursive function to print nested values
    function printValues(obj) {
        for(var k in obj) {
            if(obj[k] instanceof Object) {
                printValues(obj[k]);
            } else {
                document.write(k + ": " + obj[k]);
            };
        }
    };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
    <form action="Send.asp" method="post">    
<input type="text" name="Title" class="myid" style="border:1px double #000;">
<input type="submit" name="Submit">
</form>
```

Thanks to, Zvonko, for the code, on another side.
This one is completed.